# Goal-driven vs. goal-oriented

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What is differences between "goal-driven" and "goal-oriented"?

E.g.

> This chapter proposes modeling perception as a goal-driven planning pro- cess and considers how to guide the application of perceptual ...

vs.

> Strategic planning and different goals are common in industrial management. The existing literature describes a wealth of frameworks for goal-oriented planning ...

Comment: It boils down to the difference between *driven* and *oriented*. The former makes a much stronger statement.

Comment: goal-driven is when you pursue your goal in order to succeed. Goal-oriented is just to pursue your goal.

Answer (score 1):

[They're basically synonyms](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goal-oriented) if you can call it that.

But goal-driven sounds more aggressive than goal-oriented. But that's just my 2c.